# Combine shorthand and labelprefix in bibliography labels

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I would like to have bibliography labels of the form:

**Document X**:

```
[A-302] publication A    
[A-801] publication B
...
```

where the `A-` is a `labelprefix`, and the number is a value defined in the `.bib` file itself (i.e., not generated).

I need this because, in a different document (or `\newrefcontext` in the same document), I would like to *guarantee* that the same numbers are used for identical documents from the `.bib`, but with a different prefix:

**Document Y:**

```
[B-302] publication A
[B-801] publication B
...
```

So, those label numbers are *not* to be generated by BibTeX but maintained by a different, independent application.

Here's roughly what I currently have.

**Document X:**

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    defernumbers=true,  % NOTE: not sure about this one
    labelnumber=true,  
    style=numeric,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

    This is the first document, where references made to \cite{KEY_A} and \cite{KEY_C}.

    \newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
    \printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

**Document Y:**

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,
    defernumbers=true,  % NOTE: not sure about this one
    labelnumber=true,  
    style=numeric,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

    This is the second document, where references made to \cite{KEY_B} and \cite{KEY_C}.

    \newrefcontext[labelprefix=B]
    \printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

**`references.bib`:**

```
@Article{KEY_A,
shorthand = 0302,
author    = "Albert Einstein",
title     = "On the molecular-kinetic theory of the
            movement by heat of particles suspended in liquids at
            rest",
year      = "1905"
}

@book{KEY_B,
shorthand = 0815,
author    = {Mr. Egghead},
year      = "2001",
title     = "My superawesome book about how to be superawesome",
}

@book{KEY_C,
shorthand = 1033,
author    = {Ms. Egghead},
year      = "2002",
title     = "My normal book about how to live with someone who's convinced he's superawesome",
}
```

The result in this case just uses the `shorthand`, with the `labelprefix` completely ignored:

Document X:
[image: Document X]

Document Y:
[image: Document Y]

I have experimented with several variants of the `shorthand` option (as above). I've also tried customizing the `labelnumber`,

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\thefield{key}}
```

in an attempt to use the `key` field instead of the `shorthand` field. This doesn't work because I end up with *only* the `labelprefix` (implying `\thefield{key}` doesn't work as I expected it to).

I've tried many more things along these lines, but I just can't seem to get my custom label numbers to combine with my locally defined prefixes...How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your prefix directly to your `shorthand` with the use of a sorcemap.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage[%
%    backend=biber, % this is already the default
%    defernumbers=true, % I don't see why you'd need it here
%    labelnumber=true, % it is the default of numeric style
%    style=numeric, % it is the default of biblatex
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map[overwrite]{
            \step[fieldsource=shorthand]
            \step[fieldset=shorthand, fieldvalue={A-}]
            \step[fieldset=shorthand, origfieldval, append]
        }
    }
}


\begin{document}

    This is the first document, where references made to \cite{KEY_A}, \cite{KEY_B} and \cite{KEY_C}.

    \printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can change directly the value in your sourcemap to "B-" on your "document Y".

Comment: Nice! Exactly the sort of answer I was looking for; I learned something today, thanks!

Comment: Glad to know. I hope it was not too late to be useful.